# Ladle lists stories but they're blank

Tags: reactjs, storybook, ladle

I have an app with some stories already, and I just installed Ladle alongside Storybook. I plan on running both Ladle and Storybook – Ladle for quick iteration in developing the UI and Storybook for interaction testing and other addons.

Running `npx ladle serve` opens up the browser, and all the stories are detected. However, the display window (`main.ladle-main`) is completely blank.

On the same branch, Storybook itself runs just fine. I ran the ladle server with debug, but I don't really know what to make of any of its output.

Most of my stories have `play` functions, I don't know if that's the issue.

I also copied my global decorator from my storybook preview file to `.ladle/components.tsx`

```
import type { GlobalProvider } from "@ladle/react";
import { AppWrapper } from "../src/AppWrapper";

export const Provider: GlobalProvider = ({ children, globalState }) => (
  <>
    <header>
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,400,500,600,700"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,500,600,700"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
    </header>
    <AppWrapper>{children}</AppWrapper>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?